# WKWebView - How to get property of input type we just touch

Tags: ios, swift, input, webview, wkwebview

I would like to retrieve properties of input type field I touch when using WKWebView.

No context callback in the WKNavigationDelegate & WKUIDelegate.

Does anyone have an idea to get the context when touch input type ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, example to get id property of input type html element:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(getFocusElementId), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil) 
}

@objc private func getFocusElementId() {

    let javaScriptQuery = "document.activeElement.id"

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptQuery) { (result, error) -> Void in
        print("focus element id = \(result as? String)")
    }
}
```